# Automate NewRelic dSYM upload outside Xcode?

Tags: ios, newrelic, fastlane

My iOS project uses New Relic for tracking.  NewRelic requires uploading a dSYM file.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/configuration/upload-dsyms-bitcode-apps

I'd like to automate the process through Fastlane, but the provided script complains with:

./NewRelicAgent.framework/Versions/A/Resources/newrelic_postbuild.sh must be run from an XCode build

How can I execute this from within my standard deploy script?  I don't want to add this as an XCode post-compile run script or upload manually through the web site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I learned that the provided newrelic_postbuild.sh script simply zips up the dSYM folder and uploads it with a curl script.

Fastlane should already do the first part with the gym action.  Just specify the output directory in your normal Fastfile build lane.

```
gym({output_directory: "./build")
```

When execute, the action above dumps out the symbol file to: ./build/HelloWorld.app.dSYM.zip

To upload that, add it to a variable and execute the following:

```
NEWRELIC_URL="https://mobile-symbol-upload.newrelic.com/symbol"
NEWRELIC_KEY = "ABCd3fgH1JkLmN0PqRsTuVW8Yz"
DYSM_ZIP_FILE = "./build/HelloWorld.app.dSYM.zip"

Dir.chdir("..") do
    sh "curl -F dsym=@\"#{DYSM_ZIP_FILE}\" -H \"x-app-license-key: #{NEWRELIC_KEY}\" \"#{NEWRELIC_URL}\""
end
```

That'll do it.  If you want to just do it from within a bash script, that command would be:

```
curl -F dsym=@"${DYSM_ZIP_FILE}" -H "x-app-license-key: ${NEWRELIC_KEY}" "${NEWRELIC_URL}"
```

The benefit of this approach is that we don't have to clutter our Xcode build settings with extra scripts, and we can avoid executing unnecessary and redundant scripting code.